# Filter only a specific column in jquery filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, filter

i am modifying a jquery filter for a web page of a friend, he is using this filter from w3schools example (https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_filters.asp), but in this case jquery is looping all columns, and i only need to filter a specific column of the table. How can i "ignore" the others columns and filter the rows through a specific column?

Here is a jsfiddle example (https://jsfiddle.net/lucas2500/w7atphe3/), i would like to filter all rows by the first column (Firstname).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Sorry for any grammar mistakes.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? If you want to filter, why not do it through a specific selector? There is no code given that "loops" over all columns

Comment: @NicoHaase looks like it's a terminology/wording issue - it's not "looping all columns" rather "looking in all columns" while OP only wants to look in a single column.

Comment: What i need to do is to filter all rows based on a value of a specific column, example below: 

<th>Firistname</th>  <th>Lastname</th>
<td>Lucas</td> <td>Rafael</td>. 

What I need to do is filter all rows where "Lucas" is "Firstname", because this given code will show the rows where "Lucas" could be "Lastname".

Sorry for the bad example, but i don't have much time to think in something better right now.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the filter, it's currently checking the `.text()` of the entire row:

```
$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
```

where `this` is each `tr`.

You can replace this part to check the specific columns, eg just the first column:

```
$(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
```

Giving:

```
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
});
```

there are other ways to do this, but this is close to your original logic/code.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8owLdc2t/

Comment: That's exactly what i need. Thanks ^^